# Clearing IIS Cache from MVC3 App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, iis-7

**I need to clear the IIS cache on my server.** The exact reason is detailed below; but the reason doesn't matter. I'm 100% sure that this is the solution I need; as detailed below, I have used the process of elimination to determine that this is, indeed, the problem I'm facing, and the solution I need.

---

I have an MVC3 app that's themeable (skinnable architecture). Think of it as Wordpress; users can develop a theme, download it, and activate it on their site. The theme controls exactly the final HTML output. This is an over-simplification, since I provide an API with useful functions to be consumed by themes.

Anyway, users can change the theme of the site. The theme is currently stored in a *static variable*. When a view page is rendered, the name of the theme determines the location of the layout file (which contains references to the CSS files, etc.) and the view files. The theme is a setting that persists in the DB.

For example, if I have a theme called "Foo", then when requesting the /Admin page, I might use `/Themes/Foo/Admin.cshtml`. If I have another theme called "Bar" which does not have that file, then for /Admin it might request `/Themes/Bar/Generic.cshtml` as the layout.

The problem is that **changing a theme means that every single page on the site is outdated.** This means that any sites cached on IIS7 will show the old theme; this is incorrect. I need them to show the new theme.

Anyway, IIS7 uses caching by default. I need essentially a way to **clear the cache when a user changes the theme.** Currently, this is not happening, and users continue to see the old theme until the cache (somehow) expires itself.

I am *not* using output caching, or any other form of explicit caching; this is a "vanilla" ASP.NET MVC3 application from a caching perspective (i.e. I didn't add/configure any caching). IIS7 has its own default caching. I know this, because if I disable output caching in IIS7 for my Site, I will always see the correct theme after a change.

How can I flush the cache? Other SO questions point to using `Cache.blah`, and I tried using `HttpContext.Current` but that is null during tests (using VS test tool) -- because the ASP.NET pipeline is not used in full.

To explain, in an integration test, I basically:

- Go to localhost/Test/
- Log in (submit values into the forms)
- Change the theme by browsing to the right page and clicking the right link
- Request another page
- See if the theme changed (based on the layout/css file name).

This is all done by code; I use a C# port of `HtmlUnit`, and along with deploying my app to /Test in IIS, I can essentially browse it like an end user.

Currently, this test passes around 50% of the time. The problem is that IIS is caching the results, and I can't cleanly reliably reset the cache on the server-side.

Again, I'm not talking about clearing the session or the user-side cache; IIS itself is the culprit guilty of caching my application. Nor do I want to completely disable the cache via the IIS settings, a) because I can't force people who install my application to do that, and b) because caching is good.

So how can I force flushing the cache on the server?

For example, I tried programatically touching `web.config`; this works, but recycles my application pool, and so, kills my static variables; every request means reloading all the static vars from the DB, which kills my performance.

Comment: I tried resetting the application pool, with moderate success; sometimes it clears the cache, and sometimes not (sporadic test failures). Same for touching web.config programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just touch web.config. That's the easiest and most reliable way. Flushing the application pool programmatically is overkill.

If you have a problem finding out where web.config is in a test environment (since `System.Web.HttpRequest.Current` is null, and similar for `Server`), you can always use an app.config file to point out the location.

Again, there's no other easy way to do it; even disabling output caching, as mentioned in the question, is hard to do through `web.config` alone.

Answer (score 2):

As you requested I have amended this post:

You can use output cache, you say that the selected theme is stored in the database ( like settings for the site )  Well I would add another column with say a GUID and then use this as the varybycustom value.

Your global.asax file will be able to run code:

```
void Page_Init() {

///code here to get the GUIDforthissitestheme

var outputCacheSettings = new OutputCacheParameters() {
    Duration = Int32.MaxValue, //think its maxvalue
    VaryByCustom = GUIDforthissitestheme
};
InitOutputCache(outputCacheSettings);
```

}

At least here you will have output cache, but also every change of theme, changes the GUID so therefore changes the cache and then your page should be new.

I did something like this on a site that listed products, and when the products database was updated the key would be changed, however I can't find what site I implemented it and I work on a hell of a lot of sites.

hope this helps

Comment: sorry dude, your post actually just says you want to change the theme and that's it if you are actually wanting to change the whole site then you should maybe amend your post.   but anyway your css can change the theme and layout and everything in that single file.  if you dont need a specific div or table or whatever you set the display to none, javascript should ideally be compressed and joined at runtime into one file, again you can use the above method, finally if your needs are really this complex why not use areas instead or again set a cookie and set the _layout page rather than css

Comment: ran out of letters, but basically the above code is executed when your action is executing, not executed   your web page has this value: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}    why can that not be set dynamically  to be a separate file name  I.E  layout1, layout2  again this is without a call to database the problem is probably solved by trying to be more basic and better file name conventions if you need a more in-deft example i can help you out

Comment: I have rewritten large parts of my question. This is not the right solution -- changing views, controllers, filters, etc. Fundamentally, I need to flush the cache on the IIS server-side. See my comments about disabling output caching in IIS.

Comment: I think you should maybe try a little less aggressive of an approach as not everyone's idea of theme is going to be read in the same sense that you mean. anyway OutputCache(Duration=[maxint], VaryByParam="guid-set-in-db") notice the varybyparam  again you can set this along with your theme, use a global override to set up this varybyparam value to a guid maybe that sits in the db setting you have, any call to the server for say /home/about  will change the cache to create a new cache for that GUID and you will then get your fresh results yeah :-)

Comment: I know my concept of theme is not the usual ASP.NET MVC theme; hence why I tried to define it. I'm not convinced VaryByParam will work in my case (what am I supposed to set the GUID to? I don't have a GUID per theme, not even an ID) -- but I'll look it up. If you can edit your answer to explain that better, I can remove the DV.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. My problem is that themes are user-created and user-consumed, and may be completely different -- so I really need to clear the cache. This is the root of my problem. (I'm not trying to convince you, I just don't want you to think I'm crazy ;))

Comment: LOLOL   don't think ya crazy VaryByCustom will essentially create a cache for that param, regardless of what theme etc is applied, it dont care, if there is no cache for this new name it creates it and serves that as the latest version, to be honest i dont think you can delete the cache so easy without loads of reflection and probably permissions to private roots outside the main web route.  and below the touch method you could try doing this on the web.config, this should make it re-compile in a sense

Comment: Output caching with VaryByCustom is not sufficient, because of use-cases where I know I need to flush the cache (not something I can put in the output cache vars) like the theme change (and others).

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. You pointed out something very useful about `VaryByCustom` to me, even though it didn't solve the problem; have your +100 rep, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Set up 'Cache Rule' in 'Output caching' feature with 'File Cache Monitoring' set to 'Using file change notification'. Then 'touch' the files theme change affects, from .net code you could do:

```
System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(fileName, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're saying. Are you saying I should set up "Output Caching" with "File Cache Monitoring" in IIS? Which theme file do I touch -- changing the theme is just a matter of changing one row int he DB, not actually changing any files on the FS.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are describing sound a lot like a client side caching issue. Have you checked this with a HTTP Proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to verify if this is getting cached on the client?

If you are seeing HTTP 304's after a template change you may want to try configuring IIS (or your site template) to disable client side caching.

Comment: It's definitely a server-side issue. If I disable output caching on IIS, the issue disappears. Not coincidental. Also, I tried disabling caching on the client side via global.asax, and it didn't help (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the approach mentioned for themes is correct.
If we are using STATIC variables , then it will affect all the users and all the pages.(Which is certainly not required.)

We can think of two approaches,

1. Use theme name in url and make it as a prat if RouteData. So the url "http://myHost/BLUE/.." will return in BLUE theme and "http://myHost/RED/.." will return in RED theme. If user will change theme then url will be updated.
2. The problem with above approach is next time user browse, it will load default theme.
   So better approach will be save theme as a part of user preference. Once user logged in read the theme from DB and set the RouteData value.

Comment: -1 for trying to change my requirements. Theme changing is only one case where I know I need to flush the cache. See other CMS systems like Wordpress to understand themes better. If you can provide a solution, I will remove my DV.